# Flexbox: vertical element list not breaking to new column

Tags: css, flexbox

I try to create a responsive list of element which are aligned vertically but should to a new column if there is not enough space.

Following Snippet demonstrates my problem:

> wrong wrapping, elements are **pushing container** instead of breaking to new `column`

```css
.flex-column-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 100%;
 }
 
 .flex-item{
 height: 40px;
 background-color: aliceblue;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column-container"> 
  <div class="flex-item">
    1. Element
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    2. Element
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    3. Element
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    4. Element
  </div>
</div>
```

If I apply a fix `height` then everything is working fine but why is `max-height` expanding? Following behaviour would be perfect but with flexible height I can not count on any height like `vh`

> correct wrapping here but with `fix height`

```css
.flex-column-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 140px;
 }
 
 .flex-item{
 height: 40px;
 background-color: aliceblue;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column-container"> 
  <div class="flex-item">
    1. Element
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    2. Element
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    3. Element
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    4. Element
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    5. Element
  </div>  
</div>
```

*Or is there a completly other way of achieving the same behaviour?*

Comment: '...should to a new column if there is not enough space.' What determines the amount of space? The viewport?

Comment: height of outer parent... which just use as much space as he got

Comment: _“but why is max-height expanding?”_ - because the parent element does not have an explicit height, but that is a requirement for (max-)height in percent to work in the first place. If you add `body { height:100px; }` (or an additional container element, and that one with a height), you will immediately notice how things change in your first example. This has little to do with flexbox, but is just how percentage height calculation works.

Comment: @misorude and how could we achieve a set height without any pixel limitations? position abs and topleftbottomright: 0 ? pretty ugly isnt' it?

Comment: Well I think with flexbox you’re just using the wrong tool to begin with here - this should rather be done using CSS columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK** beside the comment from misorude I achieved the wrapping with setting `height` und `width` to *viewport-sizes* I can not imagine an other way right now.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.flex-column-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-column-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      1. Element
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      2. Element
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      3. Element
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      4. Element
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go. you can also go with `justify-content:space-around or space-between.`

```css
.flex-column-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 100%;
justify-content:left;
 }
 
 .flex-item{
 height: 40px;
 background-color: aliceblue;
 margin:0 15px 10px;
 width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column-container"> 
  <div class="flex-item">
    1. Element
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    2. Element
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    3. Element
  </div>  
  <div class="flex-item">
    4. Element
  </div>
<div class="flex-item">
    5. Element
  </div>
<div class="flex-item">
    6. Element
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you changed the flex-direction to row that's exactly not what I try to achieve... the at the position of the 4. element instead should be the 2. element

Comment: okay i get it you want to achieve the same behavior using direction column but fixed height is the problem. In current flex you can't do this without using height. but this can be achievable by javascript.

1) you can set this view by default. make a function which can calculate and apply the total height of the container to it and apply inline css and call this function in window resize as well.